# Pandas.read_csv error returning only NaN

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a problem when I use the read_csv function in pandas with a particular file :

```
personnes = pd.read_csv("personnes.csv" , sep=';' , encoding = 'latin1')
```

[The result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsrSm.png)

I don't think that there is a problem with the file itsel, since i easily open it with R.

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be the encoding is wrong, but without seeing the file or your equivalent in R I can't be sure.

Comment: If its an encoding thing it would be important to know if you're on Py 3 or Py2. Plus seeing the original csv would be helpful.

Comment: You are right it was an encoding problem. I solved it Thanks !